# Display video player if "extension" row equals mp4

Tags: php, mysql

When users are downloading files I want to allow video files to be streamed rather than downloaded automatically. I have tried using an if statement so when the extension row in the files database is MP4, rather than downloading it will display the video player, unfortunately I am getting the error "Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array", I wanted to know what the best way to get around this is, and how can I get it to function correctly?

My code is below:

```
<?php
require "require/class.config.php";
if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = intval($_GET["id"]);
    if($id <=0) {
        die("This file ID is invalid.");
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT `name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`, `url`, `owner`, `extension`, `created` FROM `files` WHERE `id` = {$id}";
        $result = $db->query($query);
        if($result) {
            if($result->rowCount() === 1) {
                $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if($result["extension"] == ("mp4")) {
                    // DISPLAY VIDEO PLAYER HERE
                } else {
                    header("Content-Type: " . $row["mime"]);
                    header("Content-Length: " . $row["size"]);
                    while(@ob_end_clean());
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $row["name"]);
                    echo $row["data"];
                }
            } else {
                echo "The file you were looking for was not found.";
            }

            @mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else {
            echo "Database query unsuccessful.";
        }
        @mysqli_close($db);
    }
} else {
    echo "No file ID was received.";
}
```

DB:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_name("session");
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "safe";
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
);
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $dbusername, $dbpassword, $options);
}
catch(PDOException $ex) {
    die("Database connection unsuccessful.");
}
```

Comment: How and where are you defining `$db`?

Comment: In the class.config.php file.

Comment: I have edited question to show $db code.

Comment: Change `if($result["extension"]` to `if($row["extension"]` and it should work.